# Php скрипт возврашает из бд таблицы id = null

Tags: php, mysql

Php скрипт обращается к таблице в БД и возвращает все данные, вот что возвращает скрипт, ниже таблица
`{"products":[{"id":null,"name":"reg","description":"dfghf","netWeight":"245","grossWeight":"2242","purchasePrice":"2452"}`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$response = array();  
$result = $database->query("SELECT * FROM Products");

if ($result != null) {
   $response["products"] = array();

  while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      $product = array();
      $product["id"] = $row["Id"];
      $product["name"] = $row["Name"];
      $product["description"] = $row["Description"];
      $product["netWeight"] = $row["NetWeight"];
      $product["grossWeight"] = $row["GrossWeight"];
      $product["purchasePrice"] = $row["PurchasePrice"];

      array_push($response["products"], $product);
  }
      $response["success"] = 1;
      $response["message"] = "Products found";

      echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: а если посмотреть в phpmyadmin? вероятно, вы его так заполнили. у вас установлено, что это автоинкриментное поле?

Comment: делал и автоинкриментное поле и нет, все равно шлет null

Comment: если оно заполнено null, то оно так и будет читаться

Comment: пользуюсь mysql workbench и заполняю прямо там в ручную, при просмотре показывает id цифры

Comment: В таблице `id` с маленькой буквы, в коде `$row["Id"]` с большой. Если я не ошибаюсь, то названия колонок key sensitive.

Comment: @Simon тогда $product["id"] = $row["Id"]; давало бы ошибку отсутствия ключа

Comment: Сработало  Id с большой, все выходит

Comment: Simon. благодарю